# huge hyper link to google maps on website doesnot load when webpage saved as html

Tags: html, web

I save web pages as html. The web pages have button having google map hyperlink directly to photos of places. Thus the link is huge. When i open html in chrome, the huge hyperlink does not load and shrinks to maps.google.com/1z,2b,3c - that's it ! I check console/inspect of html, entire huge hyper link is saved. So the problem is while uploading not saving. What to do, what an error!

Comment: The view source result has 2 https how to load 2 https in address bar while loading from saved html and not directly form website - https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Sanatana+Goswami+Bhajan+Kutir/@27.714389,77.3824194,3210a,13.1y/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipNfbOc__8lMfEuCewZwGkE5r4yz-gUQi9PZxgRQ!2e10!3e12!6shttps:/lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNfbOc__8lMfEuCewZwGkE5r4yz-gUQi9PZxgRQ=w114-h86-k-no!7i720!8i540!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x397317fef54e4b47:0xddd2b4079a9ff075!2sNandgaon+Baithakji!8m2!3d27.7158048!4d77.3826511!3m4!1s0x397317fec1dfe943:0xd118c8cf3c7a9ae0!8m2!3d27.714389!4d77.3824194"

Comment: is the question very basic or there is no calibre to answer ?